Zod Schema: Detect if a field is optional in the front-end
I'm using Zod validation for my form schemas, and Schadcn-UI's Form to build my forms. I've extracted the form <FormField /> into its own component. I would like to automatically detect if a form field is optional or not, so I can programmatically  insert a * next to the input label of all required fields to let users know which fields are required or not, instead of inserting it manually in the label every time. Is there a way to extract that from Zod?
Zod schema (password optional for testing purpose):
export const FormSchema = z.object({
    email: z.string()
        .describe('Email')
        .email({message: 'Invalid email'}),
    password: z.string()
        .describe('Password')
        .min(8,{message: 'Password must be at least 8 characters'})
        .optional(),
})

Form Field component:
interface CustomFormInputProps {
    isLoading: boolean
    control: Control<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>>
    name: FieldPath<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>>
    label: string
    placeholder: string

}

const CustomFormInput = ({isLoading, control, name, label, placeholder}: CustomFormInputProps) => {
    return (
        <FormField
            disabled={isLoading}
            control={control}
            name={name}
            render={(field) => (
                <FormItem>
                    <FormLabel>
                        {label}
                    </FormLabel>
                    {/*Test if filed is optional*/}
                    <FormControl>
                        <Input
                            type={name === 'password' ? 'password': 'text'}
                            placeholder={placeholder}
                            {...field}
                        />
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormMessage/>
                </FormItem>
            )}
        />
    );
};

export default CustomFormInput;

I've tried fiddling with the control prop, hoping intellisense will lead me to a solution, couldn't find a solution online, most likely my explanation is confusing Google

This seems like an uncommon use case. May require workarounds or "hacking" zod. I am now expert, but I would recommend digging through the zod repo on github to see if the zod validator object has any special properties offering metadata about the validator. However, in my experience most commonly the optionality on the UI is just a prop of the component that has the  in it.
